# Service name in constructor for .NET Core project

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-4.5, .net-core-3.1

I have a WPF project (running on .NET Framework 4.5) where I added a WCF service reference.

An entry is added to `app.config` with the following information:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="https://abc.xyz.com:443/ESDServiceWeb/services/ESDEntitlementServiceAPI"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ESDServiceSoapBinding2"
              contract="ESDBackupService.ESDEntitlementServiceAPI" name="ESDEntitlementServiceAPI1" />
</client>
```

When creating the object, I call:

```
ESDService.ESDEntitlementServiceAPI objServiceAPI = new ESDService.ESDEntitlementServiceAPIClient("ESDEntitlementServiceAPI1");
```

Basically the name attribute (in `app.config`) is passed into the constructor. This is fine and everything works.

I am planning to now switch to a .Net core project. I am new to .Net core. When I added the service reference, it created a json file as:

```
{
  "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15.0.40203.910",
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "https://abc.xyz.com/ESDServiceWeb/services/ESDEntitlementServiceAPI?wsdl"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Array",
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, ESDService"
    ],
    "references": [
      "System.ServiceModel, {System.ServiceModel.Primitives, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Duplex, {System.ServiceModel.Duplex, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Http, {System.ServiceModel.Http, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, {System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Primitives, {System.ServiceModel.Primitives, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Security, {System.ServiceModel.Security, 4.4.4}"
    ],
    "targetFramework": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "typeReuseMode": "All"
  }
}
```

This one has no app.config but a json file which does not have the name attribute.

How can I call the constructor now. Since it now gives an error on ESDEntitlementServiceAPI1 saying it is unknown. This name does not exist in json?

Comment: By core. You mean not .net 6 or 7?

Comment: Wcf is no longer directly supported by recent versions of .net. web api is the recommended approach now. There is, however https://www.codemag.com/Article/2211092/Using-CoreWCF-to-Move-WCF-Services-to-.NET-Core

Answer (score 0):

The WCF client libraries for .NET Core doesn't support configuration of endpoint behaviors using `App.Config`.

You will either have to create an `EndpointConfiguration` programmatically yourself and use one of the constructor overloads of the generated `ESDEntitlementServiceAPI` client that accepts an `EndpointConfiguration` and/or a `string`/`EndpointAddress`, or you could just try with the default constructor:

```
ESDService.ESDEntitlementServiceAPI objServiceAPI = 
    new ESDService.ESDEntitlementServiceAPIClient();
```